# How to send multiple HTTP requests using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, grequests

I'm trying to create a script that checks all possible top level domain combinations based on a given root domain name.

What I've done is generate a list of all possible TLD combinations and what I want to do is make multiple HTTP requests, analyze its results and determine whether a root domain name has multiple active top level domains or not.

Example:
A client of mine has this active domains:

- domain.com
- domain.com.ar
- domain.ar

I've tried using grequests but get this error:

```
TypeError: 'AsyncRequest' object is not iterable
```

Code:

```
import grequests


responses = grequests.get([url for url in urls])
grequests.map(responses)
```

Comment: give the get a list, not a for loop: `[url for url in urls]` so add two brackets ;)

Comment: What is urls? a List? From the error it looks to be a AsyncRequest.

Comment: It would be much cheaper if you just use DNS lookups. But DNS will most likely mark you as bot and ban you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, you cannot put code as a parameter. What you want is to add a list and you can using an inline for loop, like this:
`[url for url in urls]`

It is called list comprehensions and more information about this can be found over here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

So I just added two brackets:

```
import grequests

responses = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
grequests.map(responses)
```

Comment: I still have the same issue: TypeError: 'AsyncRequest' object is not iterable

Comment: Could you try my updated version? I'll update the complete answer later, if it works. But I just read the documentation and it seems they want some kind of tuple with all requests to send to the map method